# How to create multiple new symbolic links using apache ant from a fileset?

Tags: unix, ant, symlink

The symlink task in ant either create a single, record existing, recreate existing, or delete a single symbolic link.  I want to create symbolic links to all the files within a given directory within a different directory.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to achieve it (in terms of coding) is with the help of antcontrib's [For task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html)

```
<for param="file">
  <path>
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="*"/>
  </path>
  <sequential>

    <basename property="@{file}.basename" file="@{file}">
    <symlink link="${dest.dir}/${@{file}.basename}" resource="@{file}"/>
  </sequential>
</for>
```

If you don't want the dependency on ant-contrib, you may try the following (Note: I did not test it at all):

1. Create a couple of links manually in
   ${dest.dir}.
2. Run 
   in ${dest.dir}.

Now you have a template properties file that you will recreate with your build instructions:

```
<pathconvert pathsep="${line.separator}" property="file.list">
  <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includes="*"/>
</pathconvert>
<echo message="${file.list}" file="${file-list.file}" append="false"/>
```

Now massage the file with regexp filter

```
<copy file="${file-list.file}" tofile="${dest-dir}/.link.properties">
  <filterchain>
    <tokenfilter>
      <!-- I leave regex as an exercise to the reader -->
      <replaceregex pattern="..." replace="..." flags="..."/>
    </tokenfilter>
  </filterchain>
</copy>
```

Finally do symlink-recreate.

```
<symlink action="recreate">
  <fileset dir="${dest.dir}" includes=".link.properties"/>  
</symlink>
```